# Python speed testing - Time Difference - milliseconds

Tags: python, datetime, time, time-measurement

What is the proper way to compare 2 times in Python in order to speed test a section of code? I tried reading the API docs. I'm not sure I understand the timedelta thing.

So far I have this code:

```
from datetime import datetime

tstart = datetime.now()
print t1

# code to speed test

tend = datetime.now()
print t2
# what am I missing?
# I'd like to print the time diff here
```

Comment: Why didn't you print t2-t1?  What stopped you from subtracting?

Comment: Guess, I had the "it couldn't be that easy" moment.

Answer (score 258, accepted):

[`datetime.timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) is just the difference between two datetimes ... so it's like a period of time, in days / seconds / microseconds

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> b = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> c = b - a

>>> c
datetime.timedelta(0, 4, 316543)
>>> c.days
0
>>> c.seconds
4
>>> c.microseconds
316543
```

Be aware that `c.microseconds` only returns the microseconds portion of the timedelta! For timing purposes always use `c.total_seconds()`.

You can do all sorts of maths with datetime.timedelta, eg:

```
>>> c / 10
datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 431654)
```

It might be more useful to look at CPU time instead of wallclock time though ... that's operating system dependant though ... under Unix-like systems, check out the 'time' command.

Comment: Anyone interested in getting total minutes can use `int(c.total_seconds() / 60)` in this case

Comment: The [page for the timeit module](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) says that the module "avoids a number of common traps for measuring execution times." Is this approach (using datetime.now) subject to any of those pitfalls?

Comment: @kuzzooroo yes, it is! It is would be better to use timeit instead of this method! For example, I have a test in a large python project that, when measured using this method results in a supposed 0.25s runtime. In reality, and according to timeit, the runtime of said function is actually 30 seconds!

Comment: this is not usable for accurate timing since datetime is not a monotonic clock

Comment: This appears to measure the wrong time if your Python program calls C++ code via CPython.

Answer (score 88):

Since Python 2.7 there's the `timedelta.total_seconds()` method. So, to get the elapsed milliseconds:

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> a = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> b = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> delta = b - a
>>> print delta
0:00:05.077263
>>> int(delta.total_seconds() * 1000) # milliseconds
5077
```

Comment: How to accurately show this in milliseconds?

Comment: @Buffalo - It is accurate

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work if execution time is under 1 sec.  delta.total_seconds() returns 0, and thus, you cannot measure the milliseconds

Comment: Yeah, this didn't work for me, show 0sec for a bdd query

Answer (score 38):

You might want to use [the timeit module](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) instead.

Answer (score 33):

I know this is late, but I actually really like using:

```
import time
start = time.time()

##### your timed code here ... #####

print "Process time: " + (time.time() - start)
```

`time.time()` gives you seconds since the epoch. Because this is a standardized time in seconds, you can simply subtract the start time from the end time to get the process time (in seconds). `time.clock()` is good for benchmarking, but I have found it kind of useless if you want to know how long your process took. For example, it's much more intuitive to say "my process takes 10 seconds" than it is to say "my process takes 10 processor clock units"

```
>>> start = time.time(); sum([each**8.3 for each in range(1,100000)]) ; print (time.time() - start)
3.4001404476250935e+45
0.0637760162354
>>> start = time.clock(); sum([each**8.3 for each in range(1,100000)]) ; print (time.clock() - start)
3.4001404476250935e+45
0.05
```

In the first example above, you are shown a time of 0.05 for time.clock() vs 0.06377 for time.time()

```
>>> start = time.clock(); time.sleep(1) ; print "process time: " + (time.clock() - start)
process time: 0.0
>>> start = time.time(); time.sleep(1) ; print "process time: " + (time.time() - start)
process time: 1.00111794472
```

In the second example, somehow the processor time shows "0" even though the process slept for a second. `time.time()` correctly shows a little more than 1 second.

Answer (score 24):

You could also use:

```
import time

start = time.clock()
do_something()
end = time.clock()
print "%.2gs" % (end-start)
```

Or you could use the [python profilers](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html).

Comment: When using `start = time.clock()` it prints `DeprecationWarning: time.clock has been deprecated in Python 3.3 and will be removed from Python 3.8: use time.perf_counter or time.process_time instead`.

Answer (score 6):

The following code should display the time detla...

```
from datetime import datetime

tstart = datetime.now()

# code to speed test

tend = datetime.now()
print tend - tstart
```

Answer (score 4):

You could simply print the difference:

```
print tend - tstart
```

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look into the [profile](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) modules. You'll get a better read out of where your slowdowns are, and much of your work will be full-on automated.

Comment: Nice idea! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am not a Python programmer, but [I do know how to use Google](http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_python/datesandtimes.html) and here's what I found: you use the "-" operator. To complete your code:

```
from datetime import datetime

tstart = datetime.now()

# code to speed test

tend = datetime.now()
print tend - tstart
```

Additionally, it looks like you can use the strftime() function to format the timespan calculation in order to render the time however makes you happy.

Answer (score 3):

Arrow: Better dates & times for Python

```
import arrow
start_time = arrow.utcnow()
end_time = arrow.utcnow()
(end_time - start_time).total_seconds()  # senconds
(end_time - start_time).total_seconds() * 1000  # milliseconds
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `time.time()` instead, which outputs unix time with high precision.

Use this code:

```
from time import time

tstart = time()
doSomething()
tend = time()
difference = tend - tstart
print("The doSomething function took {} seconds to execute".format(difference))
```

Answer (score 2):

time.time() / datetime is good for quick use, but is not always 100% precise.  For that reason, I like to use one of the std lib [profilers](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) (especially hotshot) to find out what's what.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a custom function that mimic's Matlab's/Octave's `tic` `toc` functions.

**Example of use:**

```
time_var = time_me(); # get a variable with the current timestamp

... run operation ...

time_me(time_var); # print the time difference (e.g. '5 seconds 821.12314 ms')
```

**Function :**

```py
def time_me(*arg):
    if len(arg) != 0: 
        elapsedTime = time.time() - arg[0];
        #print(elapsedTime);
        hours = math.floor(elapsedTime / (60*60))
        elapsedTime = elapsedTime - hours * (60*60);
        minutes = math.floor(elapsedTime / 60)
        elapsedTime = elapsedTime - minutes * (60);
        seconds = math.floor(elapsedTime);
        elapsedTime = elapsedTime - seconds;
        ms = elapsedTime * 1000;
        if(hours != 0):
            print ("%d hours %d minutes %d seconds" % (hours, minutes, seconds)) 
        elif(minutes != 0):
            print ("%d minutes %d seconds" % (minutes, seconds))
        else :
            print ("%d seconds %f ms" % (seconds, ms))
    else:
        #print ('does not exist. here you go.');
        return time.time()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "redis-get-response.py", line 22, in <module>
    time_var = time_me(); # get a variable with the current timestamp
  File "redis-get-response.py", line 20, in time_me
    return time.time()
NameError: name 'time' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You could use timeit like this to test a script named module.py

```
$ python -mtimeit -s 'import module'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start = datetime.now() 

#code for which response time need to be measured.

end = datetime.now()
dif = end - start
dif_micro = dif.microseconds # time in microseconds
dif_millis = dif.microseconds / 1000 # time in millisseconds
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs something like this to analyze delays between log entries for example ... etc.

```
def get_time_diff_between_timestruct_tuples(timestruct_tuples):
    """
    expecting input like:
    [(0, datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 27, 16, 6, 8, 590892)),
    (1, datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 27, 16, 6, 8, 591833)),
    (2, datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 27, 16, 6, 9, 434053)),
    (3, datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 27, 16, 6, 9, 878021)), ...]
    
    output like:
    [0.941, 0.84222, 0.443968, ...]
    """
    
    def seconds_mms_diff(t0, t1):
        diff = t1 - t0
        s = diff.seconds
        mms = diff.microseconds
        return float(f"{s}.{mms}")
    
    timediffs = []
    init = timestruct_tuples[0][1]
    idx = 0
    while idx < (len(timestruct_tuples)-1):
        timediffs.append(seconds_mms_diff(init, timestruct_tuples[idx+1][1]))
        idx += 1
        init = timestruct_tuples[idx][1]
    return timediffs
```