# Calculate time span in Python

Tags: python, datetime

im using Python v2.x on Windows 64bit

I would like to record two moments in real time and calculate the time span.
Please see code as following:

```
current_time1 = datetime.datetime.now().time() # first moment

# ... some statement...some loops...take some time...

current_time2 = datetime.datetime.now().time() # second moment

time_span = current_time1 - current_time2
```

Apparently the last line is not executable because current_time is not integer, so my question is, how to convert this statement to integer to do the math? Convert to seconds is my first thought...

Comment: Already answered there: [datetime example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766335/python-speed-testing-time-difference-milliseconds) and there [timeit example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370801/measure-time-elapsed-in-python)

Answer (score 8):

Subtracting a one `datetime.datetime.now()` from another gives you a `datetime.timedelta` instance. If you run `dir()` on it,  you will likely find some useful functions.

```
>>> x = datetime.datetime.now()
# wait a second or two or use time.sleep()
>>> y = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> z = y - x
>>> type(z)
<type 'datetime.timedelta'>
>>> print(list(filter(lambda x: not x.startswith("_"), dir(z))))
['days', 'max', 'microseconds', 'min', 'resolution', 'seconds', 'total_seconds']
>>> print(z.total_seconds())
2.31
```

Answer (score 4):

```
current_time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
time.sleep(50)
current_time2 = datetime.datetime.now()

print (current_time2 - current_time1)
```

or alternatively

```
time1 = time.time()
time.sleep(50)
time2 = time.time()
print("%s seconds"%(time2-time1))
```

Comment: Oops, got an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and datetime.time

Comment: there is no `datetime.time` in my answer ... you have clearly not copied and pasted it ...

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

current_time1 = time.clock()
do_something()
current_time2 = time.clock()
print "%.2gs" % (current_time2-current_time1)
```

EDIT:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

datetime.combine(date.today(), current_time2) - datetime.combine(date.today(), current_time1)
```

Comment: oops, got an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and datetime.time

Comment: Try this:

`from datetime import datetime, date

datetime.combine(date.today(), current_time2) - datetime.combine(date.today(), current_time1)`

Answer (score -1):

In python 3.x use [time.perf_counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter)

```py
import time

t1_start = time.perf_counter()

do_something() # your code goes here

t1_stop = time.perf_counter()
print("Elapsed time:", t1_stop - t1_start) # print performance indicator
```

Comment: While this might "work" to measure a delta in time, it does not provide a time span.