# how to extract a particular frame from video stream using Opencv & Python

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I want to **extract and process** frame every **200 ms** from video stream from **webcam**, I tried frameRate = cap.get(5) ie.(CAP_PROP_FPS) and frameIndex = cap.get(1) ie.(CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES) but I get **frameRate = 0.0 & frameIndex  = -1.0**.
Please help, Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

For simple application I would use cv2.waitKey() in myyour code to introduce delay. If you want to have one frame every exactly 200ms you have to addtime measurement, for example like described here:

[Python speed testing - Time Difference - milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766335/python-speed-testing-time-difference-milliseconds)

I would include one if statement in my code and wait untill time difference is equal 200ms.

As I mentioned on the begining it is simple, not the best solution, but easiest to implement to begin with.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried what you've suggested (datetime) and it worked for me because my while loop(while cap.isOpened():) is not taking more than 100-150 ms. As you said it is a simple solution not best, having said that it is simple & best as well because, if only one frame takes more than 200 ms for processing anyhow I'm going to miss the next frame.