# Convert execution time to milliseconds: time.time()

Tags: python, mongodb, performance-testing, latency

How can I convert the execution time to milliseconds.
I already multiplied the start and end time to 1000.

I used time.time()

[Execution Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1T15.png)

**Result:**
('Start time: ', 1596465418538.365)

Remove.IntNonIdUniqueIndex

('End time: ', 1596465418538.399)

('Execution time: ', 3.409385681152344e-05)

Comment: This is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766335/python-speed-testing-time-difference-milliseconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time.time()` basic unit is second. It's enough to multiply the difference between `end` and `start` by 1000 to get the milliseconds.

```
import time

start = time.time()
time.sleep(1)
end = time.time()
d = end - start
print(f'executed in {d} seconds or {d*1000} milliseconds')

executed in 1.003673791885376 seconds or 1003.673791885376 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are measuring program execution times, it is best to use [`time.monotonic()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic) or [`time.monotonic_ns()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.monotonic_ns).
These functions are guaranteed *never* to go backwards even in the event of system clock updates.

The first returns a value in seconds, the second in nanoseconds.